# How did Ukrainian neo-Nazis and Ukrainian Jews coexist without bloody incidents?

Tags: ukraine, antisemitism

Before the invasion, Ukraine had 360-400 thousand Jews living there. And [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Ukraine#:%7E:text=As%20of%202012%2C%20Ukraine%20had,%2C%20Dnipro%2C%20Kharkiv%20and%20Odessa.), the Jewish population has been increased.

On the other hand, Ukraine has a [sizable neo-Nazi presence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_neo-Nazi_organizations#Ukraine).

How did Ukrainian neo-Nazis and Ukrainian Jews coexist without bloody incidents?

Comment: Many countries have both Jews and neo Nazis.  Those in Ukraine probably coexist in much the same way as those elsewhere.  Are you interested in Ukraine for some particular reason, or do you want an answer that explains the effect of modern civil systems in general on people's tendency to commit hate crimes?

Comment: "Ukraine has a very strong neo-Nazi presence" - define "very strong". I know most of the discussion around neo-Nazism in Ukraine has centered on the Azov Battalion, whose membership is [listed by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azov_Battalion) as being around 1,000 people.

Comment: @F1Krazy, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_neo-Nazi_organizations#Ukraine

Comment: @user366312 Of the other three organisations listed there, two no longer exist and the third has similar membership numbers to the Azov Battatlion (about 1,000). 2,000 neo-Nazis is of course 2,000 too many, but I have yet to be convinced that Ukraine's neo-Nazi presence is significantly stronger than the other countries mentioned on that list.

Comment: Ukraine is a very complex country and I suspect this site could offer a good answer to this question. For those that wish to understand Ukraine I will suggest 2 books: Bloodlands, and Kleine Geschichte der Ukraine (unfortunately no english version) voting to reopen

Comment: @user366312 If you notice from that list, the number of listed organizations is not unusual among European countries; though I think this is a poor measure anyways, as number of orgs need not be related to number of adherents, I don't see how this is evidence of anything "very strong" in relative terms.

Comment: Is the premise of the question correct? In some countries, such as the United States, there is substantial documentation of anti-Semitic hate crimes, meaning that incidents between neo-Nazis and Jews often are documented. In Ukraine, there may not be, and what information there is may be in Ukrainian and thus hard to find for people who do not speak that language. I do know that the leader of a Ukrainian neo-Nazi group was killed in a clash with anti-fascist protesters in Odessa. For all we know, some of those protesters could have been Jews.

Comment: What is "sizable" exactly? We have a "sizable" Neo Nazi presence in the United States too, but while they're a cause for concern they're hardly overwhelming. This sounds like you're falling for the various Russian propaganda that used the existence of those Nazis as an excuse for their completely unjustified and morally indefensible invasion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a very small fraction of Neo-Nazis relative to the total population of Ukraine. The Jews are more influential than Neo-Nazis in economical, cultural and political spheres in Ukraine.

Several examples of prominent Jews in Ukraine are former comedian, writer and actor, and now President of Ukraine Volodymyr Zelensky and oligarch Igor Kolomoysky.

Somewhat ironically, Jewish candidate Rabinovich obtained more votes during elections of 2014 than the Right Sector (~Neo-Nazi?) candidate.

I know the general picture, but not the exact numbers from personal experience (prior to 2010) and from personal communication, from following the public discourse on TV and from social media across many years.

**REFERENCES:**

> In the 2014 presidential election, he received 2.25 percent of the overall vote.

*Vadim Rabinovich - Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vadim_Rabinovich*

> In the 25 May 2014 presidential race Yarosh received 127,000 votes, 0.7% of the total cast.

*Right Sector - Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_Sector*

Comment: If Jews are getting more votes than the neo-Nazis, then, how are the neo_Nazis justifying their existence in the Ukrainian society?

Comment: @user366312 It’s tough for Neo-Nazis in Ukraine! I have to find them and ask… To be fare, antisemitism probably still exists in Ukraine. It used to exist in 1980s for sure. But antisemitism is one thing, and Neo-Nazis is quite another. In the 1980s, I have not seen any Neo-Nazis.

Comment: *But antisemitism is one thing, and Neo-Nazis is quite another.* --- Could you please elaborate? Coz, I am confused at this point. I thought the original Nazism had something to do with antisemitism. Therefore, why are neo-Nazis not anti-semitic? I doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @user366312 The sets of Neo-Nazis and antisemites overlap, but one is not a subset of the other. All I am saying in my comment is that in 1980s there was antisemitism but not neonazism.